# Change the look for completed tasks

Tags: tasks, online

Is there any way we can change the look for completed tasks in Sharepoint Online? For example - different colors, bold text or something else. One of our client don't like current look.
[image]

Comment: You can also show the tasks status in more graphical way by using solution given at this site. https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a

Answer (score 1):

Try to Add the following code within script editor in AllItems page of task list.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {

   SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
     OnPostRender: function(ctx) {


       var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
       for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
       {
          var status = rows[i]["Status"];
          if(status == "Completed") {
          var rowId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
          var row = document.getElementById(rowId); 
          row.style.backgroundColor = "green";
           }
       }
     }
   }); 

});
</script>
```